# Laravel 5.2 balde/css stops working when routing sub url through controller

Tags: php, css, laravel, routes

I can't figure it out what could cause this issue, but i'am pretty sure it simple. I am extending main view main.blade.php (located in views folder). This includes css from partials folder.

I have two pages: Enquire, Approved enquire. (both located in views/trader/ folder.) only difference is routing, one would have /enquires the other would have /enquires/approved.

```
Blade/Css working if on main route: Route::get('/enquires','Trader\PagesController@getEnquires');
Blade/Css does not work when using suburl: Route::get('/enquires/approved','Trader\PagesController@getApproved');
```

Please refer to this image:
[routing display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTDUW.png)

If you require any other information please let me know,
Tahnks in advance,
Dan

Comment: It seems blade works, but your CSS file(s) do not load. Can you show whole `<head>` section of generated HTML please.

Comment: It is strange because it does work if i take off the /enquires from routing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in how you're creating links to assets (images, CSS and JS files). To make it work, use Laravel `asset()` helper:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/theme.css' }}">
```

Which will create full path to an asset.

Also, you must keep all assets inside public directory of your project, for example: `/laravel_project/public/css/theme.css`

Comment: Ohh.. what a damn mistake, I've done that for admin but forgot for front end.. thanks so much and apologise.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   

    <title>@yield('title')</title>  

    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Trusted Workers - Find local tradesmen">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800%7CShadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">


    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-blog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-shop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-animate.css">

    <!-- Current Page CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/rs-plugin/css/layers.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/rs-plugin/css/navigation.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/circle-flip-slideshow/css/component.css" media="screen">

    <!-- Skin CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skins/default.css">

    <!-- Theme Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Head Libs -->
    <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```